# Can not retract very-low-quality flag after the post is upvoted

Tags: support, flags, low-quality-posts, retracted-flags

It is known that we can not flag a post as "very-low-quality" if it has a positive score. But for example, if I initially flag a post with zero score as "very-low-quality", then when later this post is upvoted, I will not be able to retract my flag. Why?

Well, I just did a random experiment on this post: [S3 method function arguments - class flexibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51231905/s3-method-function-arguments-class-flexibility). it is actually a great post so after my experimental flag I voted it up, then I don't have the "retract" option. Can we fix this?

> So you click the flag link and then the blue button doesn't say retract flag? – rene

Yes, that's right.

---

Oh, for some reason OP just edited that post, so I got a "useful" flag. :)

---

The intension of my question is, when we later realize that we have wrongly flagged a post as "very-low-quality" in for example a review queue, but the post has already been upvoted by (possibly many) others, then it looks like we can only wait for moderators to decline our flags without any remedy. That is sort of sad.

Comment: So you click the flag link and then the blue button doesn't say *retract flag*?

Comment: Yeah, an edit marks flags valid, that is known behavior. The upvote thing is new to me.

Comment: I repro-ed it here on Meta on your post so it seems to be a feature. After I un-upvoted your question I was able to retract my flag again. Weird.

Comment: You can't retract the flag because an *edit* automatically cleared the flag, marking it as helpful (it's assumed an edit is more likely to make a post no longer so illegible that a low-quality flag was warranted in the first place).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yeah, but even without that edit I can't

Comment: @李哲源: I'm looking for confirmation but the most likely explanation is that the upvote clears the flag.

Comment: @MartijnPieters If the vote clears the flag, then I should get a "useful" flag, but that won't happen. My flag will still have a "pending" status.

Comment: You don't have any such flags currently. Are you *sure* that that's what happens?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I did have one here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421826/what-is-androids-file-system/51222480#51222480 and that is why I ask here.

Comment: That post was upvoted **before** you flagged it. By 14 seconds.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Well then, you are most welcome to make an experiment yourself. I think when I initially flagged that post it had a -1 score; not sure why that downvote was invalidated later.

Comment: @MartijnPieters there is definitely different behavior in the flag dalog between an up voted and zero score post: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAjgh.gif

Comment: @rene "you have retracted your flag" - that came from your early experiment (when this post was still 0-score), right?

Comment: @李哲源 yes it does

Comment: @rene: sure, so the dialog was loaded for that post before it was upvoted, then flagged after.

Comment: @Floern How did you find that? I did not find one earlier. But this is indeed a bug, right? It was already brought to notice 2 years ago.

Comment: @李哲源: not sure why you are using all-caps, no need to shout. I'm just trying to find an example of such a flag, so I can diagnose it. And yes, as a moderator, my view on the flag dialogs is a little different.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Cap for shouting?! I though it just another way for highlighting

Comment: @李哲源: yes, all-caps is the [internet equivalent of shouting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Association_with_shouting). https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/netiquette/images/5/57/Caps_Lock.jpg